# Missing dropdown menu bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why my drop down bar navigation is not appearing?

The site is above and the code is here:

http://pastebin.com/Tv9gkC9v

I tried including all of the main jQuery libraries aswell as the bootstrap library, could someone possibly spot out what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;"` to your `<ul>`

[image: screenshot]